# EntitySet - is there a sane reason that IList.Add doesn't set assigned?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, entityset

There are 3 ways of adding items to most lists...

- via a direct public API method, typically `Add(SomeType)`
- via the generic `IList<T>.Add(T)` interface
- via the non-generic `IList.Add(object)` interface method

and you normally expect them to behave *more or less* the same. However, LINQ's `EntitySet<T>` is... peculiar on both 3.5 and 4.0; the `IList` API ***does not*** flag the set as "assigned" - the other two mechanisms ***do*** - this sounds trivial, but it is important in that it heavily influences serialization (i.e. causes it to be skipped) in the boilerplate code.

Example:

```
EntitySet<string> set1 = new EntitySet<string>();
set1.Add("abc");
Debug.Assert(set1.Count == 1); // pass
Debug.Assert(set1.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues, "direct"); // pass

EntitySet<string> set2 = new EntitySet<string>();
IList<string> typedList = set2;
typedList.Add("abc");
Debug.Assert(set2.Count == 1); // pass
Debug.Assert(set2.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues, "typed list"); // pass

EntitySet<string> set3 = new EntitySet<string>();
IList untypedList = set3;
untypedList.Add("abc");
Debug.Assert(set3.Count == 1); // pass
Debug.Assert(set3.HasLoadedOrAssignedValues, "untyped list"); // FAIL
```

Now... this is deeply surprising to me; so much so that it took me over 2 hours of tracking upwards through code to isolate what was happening. So...

is there ***any*** sane reason for this? Or is this just a bug?

(FWIW, there was also an issue in `set.Assign(set)` in 3.5, but this is now fixed in 4.0.)

Comment: The Add() method calls OnModified, the IList.Add() explicit implementation does not.  Nobody uses it of course, unused code has bugs.  The return type of IList.Add() was surely the bug generator.

Comment: Logged on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/671989/entityset-t-s-ilist-add-implementation-does-not-have-consistent-effects

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Interestingly, this has been identified for several versions now (you stated that a 3.5 issue was fixed in 4.0). [Here is a post from 2007.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/5ae5e5f5-bef5-4a63-aadc-98ed8b30c8d1/) The rest of the `IList` methods in 4.0 are correctly tied to the `IList<T>` methods. I think that there are 2 likely explanations (of the bug/feature variety):

1. This is an actual bug that Microsoft has not yet fixed.
2. This is a feature that some other Microsoft code is <strike>exploiting</strike> leveraging to add items *without* setting the `HasLoadedOrAssignedValues`.

It is probably both - a bug that other code inside the framework is counting on. Sounds like someone said to themselves:

> No one is really going to cast this into an IList and then call the Add method, right?

Answer (score 8):

Surprisingly, the difference seems rooted in the fact that the `IList.Add` and `IList<T>.Add` methods actually have **different semantics**:

- The `IList.Add` method fails if the entity being added is already present
- The `LIst<T>.Add` method removes and then re-adds an entity if is is already present

The apparent reason for this difference is that `IList.Add` interface method is defined to return the index of the added entity, which for a typical implementation of `IList.Add` will always be the `Count` of the collection prior to the `Add`.

In any case, because the two implementations are intentionally different, it seems the authors simply accidentally omitted the `this.OnModified()` call in the `IList.Add` version.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug to me. ILSpy shows the differences between the two implementations:

```
int IList.Add(object value)
{
    TEntity tEntity = value as TEntity;
    if (tEntity == null || this.IndexOf(tEntity) >= 0)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("value");
    }
    this.CheckModify();
    int count = this.entities.Count;
    this.entities.Add(tEntity);
    this.OnAdd(tEntity);
    return count;
}

// System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<TEntity>
/// <summary>Adds an entity.</summary>
/// <param name="entity">The entity to add.</param>
public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("entity");
    }
    if (entity != this.onAddEntity)
    {
        this.CheckModify();
        if (!this.entities.Contains(entity))
        {
            this.OnAdd(entity);
            if (this.HasSource)
            {
                this.removedEntities.Remove(entity);
            }
            this.entities.Add(entity);
            this.OnListChanged(ListChangedType.ItemAdded, this.entities.IndexOf(entity));
        }
        this.OnModified();
    }
}
```

It looks like the IList implementation simply neglects to call a couple of event invokers (`OnListChanged` and `OnModified`) that LINQ to SQL probably relies on to track its changes. If this had been intentional, I would have expected them to also leave out the call to `OnAdd`.

Why they don't simply have `IList.Add` cast the value to `TEntity` and call the generic `Add` method is beyond me.

Comment: "Why they don't simply have `IList.Add` cast the value to `TEntity` and call the generic `Add` method is beyond me." That's pretty much what Mono's implementation does.